# How can I write an Android App to get some sort of unique value?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, serial-number, imei

I need to have some code in my android APP that gets some sort of unique value (a value that is unique to the handset). I'm using the Xamarin/C# environment with Visual Studio. I understand that not all android phones expose the phone number to programmatic access.

My current approach is to use the **Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager** class.

```cs
Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager manager = null;
manager = activity.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.TelephonyService);
// [RequiresPermission("android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE")]
imei_value = manager.Imei;
meid_value = manager. Meid;
carrier = manager.NetworkOperatorName;
country = manager.NetworkCountryIso;
sn = manager.SimSerialNumber;
initialized = true;
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "initialized phone");
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "carrier: " +  carrier);
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "country: " + country);
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "serial:  [" + sn + "]");
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "MEID:    [" + meid_value + "]");
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "IMEI:    [" + imei_value + "]");
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "MEID(2): [" + manager.GetMeid(0) + "]");
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "IMEI(2): [" + manager.GetImei(0) + "]");
Log.Debug("DEBUG", "phone:   [" + manager.Line1Number + "]");
```

This is what the debugger generates:

```
11-11 17:00:45.690 D/DEBUG   (24041): initialized phone
11-11 17:00:45.691 D/DEBUG   (24041): carrier: Verizon
11-11 17:00:45.691 D/DEBUG   (24041): country: us
11-11 17:00:45.691 D/DEBUG   (24041): serial:  []
11-11 17:00:45.691 D/DEBUG   (24041): MEID:    []
11-11 17:00:45.691 D/DEBUG   (24041): IMEI:    []
11-11 17:00:45.694 D/DEBUG   (24041): MEID(2): []
11-11 17:00:45.698 D/DEBUG   (24041): IMEI(2): []
11-11 17:00:45.703 D/DEBUG   (24041): phone:   [xxx866xxxx]
```

The phone I'm testing on is a **Google Pixel 3**

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Comment: Can you explain why you need to use an ID "that is unique to the handset"?  In general, using hardware IDs is appropriate only if "it's required for [mobile] carrier-related functionality".  (With respect to the IMEI in particular, see section 8 of RFC 7254; note that in particular that IMEIs and serial numbers are not appropriate for identifying users, since devices can change ownership from one user to another.)

Comment: I've heard that in general, manager.Line1Number is NOT guaranteed to come up with a number (if the phone number does not reside on the SIM card).  I can ask the user to provide his/her phone number - but then will need to trust that the user was accurate/honest in her/his entry. I need a backup means of identifying the phone.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have some code in my android APP that gets some sort of unique value (a value that is unique to the handset).

For one way, you can use TelephonyManager.DeviceId Property to get Device Id.

```
 Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager manager = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)this.ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
            
            string deviceIde = manager.DeviceId;
```

For another way , you can get android.OS.Build.SERIAL, it is unique. But note that it was only added in API level 9, and it may not be present on all devices. To get a unique ID on earlier platforms, you'll need to read something like the MAC address or IMEI.

```
string id= Android.OS.Build.Serial;
```

Generally, try reading all the possible IDs, and use whichever are available. See this article for [guidance](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html).

Comment: manager.DeviceId has been deprecated. But the Android.OS.Build.Serial represents a possibility that's news to me! I'll give it a try and post the results afterward.

Comment: Here are the results:

11-13 16:00:42.742 D/DEBUG   (32219): initialized phone
11-13 16:00:42.742 D/DEBUG   (32219): carrier: Verizon
11-13 16:00:42.742 D/DEBUG   (32219): country: us
11-13 16:00:42.742 D/DEBUG   (32219): serial:    [unknown]
11-13 16:00:42.756 D/DEBUG   (32219): serial[2]: []
11-13 16:00:42.756 D/DEBUG   (32219): IMEI:      []
11-13 16:00:42.761 D/DEBUG   (32219): MEID(2):   []
11-13 16:00:42.771 D/DEBUG   (32219): IMEI(2):   []
11-13 16:00:42.781 D/DEBUG   (32219): phone:     [xxx866xxx]
the result of the Build.Serial is the string "unknown"

Comment: @Gary, although manager.DeviceId has been deprecated, but I can also get value from it. and I am not sure about your second reply. For Android.OS.Build.Serial, it may not be present on all devices.